# Is it possible to load an older version of Firebase JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, firebase

I want to confirm that it is not possible to load an older version of Firebase JavaScript SDK.

I took a look at the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js) and the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) and it seems there is no way to load the older version of the API.

Can someone confrim?

Comment: `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.10.1/firebase.js"></script>` current version is 4.12.0 (as stated in release notes) but in this page [setup js](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) there is an older version, so yes you can

Comment: Couple follow up questions: Is this documented and/or supported?

Comment: *firebaser here* If we'd remove the previous version when we publish a new one, we'd be breaking hundreds of thousands of apps with every release.  Keeping previous versions of an SDK available at their previous URL is really just a standard practice for web libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, as you can see in this page:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

They are loading the following:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.10.1/firebase.js"></script>
```

while the latest version is `4.12.0` released in march 20.

So you are able to use older versions, but of course not all older versions are supported anymore.

It is also better to always use the newest version, to be able to use the latest additions to the sdk.